# Node JS: MySQL is saving incorrect DateTime value in database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, timestamp

I am trying to save a record into a MySQL database using Node.js. Below is the code

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});

exports.createJobApplication = (event, context, callback) => {

        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

        const sql = "INSERT INTO job_applications (idjob, iduser, cover_letter, applied_date) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        con.query(sql, [jobApplication.idjob, jobApplication.iduser, jobApplication.cover_letter, 1636366620000], function(err, jobApplicationResult) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err.toString());

                        con.rollback(function() {
                            var response = errorCodes.save_failed;
                            callback(null, response);
                        });

                    } else {}

                }
```

Unfortunatly, I am failing to save the date as required. The above date `1636366620000` really represents `2021-11-08 10:17:00` but in MySQL database what I see is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

The `applied_date` field in MySQL is a `DateTime` field as well.

In addition to the hardcoded values I tried below JSON, but I get the same result

```
{
   "job_application":{
      "idjob":5,
      "iduser":112,
      "cover_letter":"ABCD EFGH IJK LMNOP QRST UV WXYZ",
      "applied_date":1636366620000
   },
   "milestones":[
      {
         "title":"title",
         "start_date":1636366620000,
         "end_date":1636366620000,
         "cost":250.0,
         "is_deleted":false
      },
      {
         "title":"title two",
         "start_date":1615544220000000,
         "end_date":1615544220000000,
         "cost":250.0,
         "is_deleted":false
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: As far as I know, if you define `date` for a field in database, you can't save timestamp in that. To save timestamps just change the field type to `string` in your model

Comment: @SoroushBgm: I'm afraid. That is very wrong.

Comment: You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert a numeric timestamp to a `DATE` or `DATETIME`. You'll need to divide by 1000, since JavaScript timestamps are in milliseconds, but Unix timestamps are seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I have forgotted to wrap my DateTime integer with `new Date()`. So technically, this is how it should be

```
const sql = "INSERT INTO job_applications (idjob, iduser, cover_letter, applied_date) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        con.query(sql, [jobApplication.idjob, jobApplication.iduser, jobApplication.cover_letter, new Date(1636366620000)], function(err, jobApplicationResult)
```

Comment: So I wasn't very wrong :)

Comment: @SoroushBgm: Still, you are. `String` and `Date` are not the same type. Plus, saving a `Timestamp` as a `String` in a model will make lot of inconsistency throughout an application. You can, but it doesn't mean you should. However this can also depend on the language. In Java we can use `java.sql.Timestamp`, in Dart we can use `int` and so on. The advantage of these data types are it "limits" the possibility of saving junk data and avoid confusion. Plus it gives you the ease of modifying data, like timestamp to second/milliseconds... .

Comment: @SoroushBgm: However in `String` field in model, you can save `abcd`, `1234` or even `☺☺☺☺` if you want.